# Questions about what the legal status means on Google Patents

Tags: law, google-patents, google, legal-status, worldwideapplications

[image]

This patent has been shown to be in an active status in the US since 2013. However, it appears to have been marked as Abandoned in 2020. In this case, I am curious whether the patent has no legal effect in the US after 2020, or if the abandonment only applies to modifications or additions to the patent that were rejected in 2020.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don’t you give us a link so we can help you. At least the document number. That picture relates to applications, not the issued patent.

Answer (score 0):

The image you provided relates only to patent applications and doesn't give you any useful information regarding the granting of a patent or its status. When you see multiple dates, they are likely related applications sharing priority.

Here is a larger image form another patent. Notice some of the application country codes are in blue. If you hover over those you can get a pop up message regarding the application status. Looking lower you can see more relevant information about the patent (if indeed the document you are looking at is a patent and not an application. In this case the patent status is active and will expire on October 19, 2026. If you had provided a link to the document or at least the document number we could have provided specific answers to your question.

[image]